# How to run tests from multiple folders in python-behave?

Tags: python, python-behave

Is there a way to run tests from multiple folders with a single `behave` invocations.

Below is the problem in detail. I have two features folders named sample1 and sample2. I want to run the tests within each folder from a single behave invocation. I see a `[paths option]`(https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html?highlight=paths#configuration-files) in configuration files, but not much documentation is available. Is it possible to load multiple steps files specific to each directory?

```
└── testsuites
    ├── sample1
    │   ├── cpcode.feature
    │   └── steps
    │       └── cpcode.py
    └── sample2
        ├── cpcode.feature
        └── steps
            └── cpcode.py
```

I have configured `behave.ini` with `paths=./testsuites/sample1 ./testsuites/sample2`. But test results indicate the even for Scenario in sample2 folder, steps from sample1 is picked.

Comment: How do you intend to run this? From command line, from any IDE or something else?

Comment: I would want this to be executed from a Jenkins instance/shell.

Answer (score 0):

Actually paths parameter in behave.ini is to set default value. And you should set only one folder here.

> [behave]
>
> paths=sample1/.

(Make sure you added [behave] in that file)

So when you need to run a feature, just run command:

> behave -k cpcode_sample1.feature

or you can add the folder explicitly:

> behave -k sample1/cpcode_sample1.feature
>
> behave -k sample2/cpcode_sample2.feature

Hope it helps.